# Как понять, сколько CPU потребляет zram для своей работы?

Tags: linux, debian

Насколько я знаю, zram сжимает данные в ОЗУ, и из-за этого повышается нагрузка на CPU.
И как понять, сколько CPU потребляет zram в данный момент времени?
В списке процессов я не вижу zram. Как тогда это понять?

Comment: Это модуль ядра, он не может быть процессом.

Comment: @Kotomi как же тогда понять, сколько CPU потребяет zram?

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/blockdev/zram.txt